# Private Route - cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to do a token check when using Route. I liked one solution, but for some reason it does not want to work and gives an error:

> Class constructor App cannot be invoked without 'new'

```
const RequireAuth = (Component) => { 
    return class App extends Component { 
        componentWillMount() { 
            const getToken = localStorage.getItem('token'); 
            if(!getToken) { 
               this.props.history.replace({pathname: '/'}); 
            } 
        } 
        render() { 
           return <Component {...this.props} /> 
        }
    } 
} 

export { RequireAuth };
```

Usage:

```
...
<PrivateRoute path="/profile" component={RequireAuth(Profile)} />
...
```

I have no idea why it is coming out and how to fix it. Have a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be masking the react `Component` type. Try changing the name of the parameter, or change to functional component if possible. Also, `componentWillMount` is soon to be deprecated, you really should use `componentDidMount` instead.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const requireAuth = (component) => { // lowercase to not conflict with React.Component!
  return class App extends Component { 
    componentDidMount() { 
      const getToken = localStorage.getItem('token'); 
      if(!getToken) { 
        this.props.history.replace({pathname: '/'}); 
      } 
    }

    render() { 
      const Component = component; // convert to PascalCase for react use
       return <Component {...this.props} /> 
    }
  } 
} 

export { requireAuth };
```

or

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const requireAuth = (Component) => { 
  return props => {
    useEffect(() => {
      const getToken = localStorage.getItem('token'); 
      if(!getToken) { 
         props.history.replace({pathname: '/'}); 
      } 
    }, []); // empty dependency array runs once on mount

    return <Component {...this.props} />;
  } 
} 

export { requireAuth };
```

I should note though that react's convention for Higher Order Components is to camelCase the name and not render them directly, and instead decorate an existing component.

- `const RequiresAuthMyComponent = requireAuth(MyComponent);`
- `export default requireAuth(MyComponent);`

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure javascript class is not call such as you have mention (App Class).

So you can try something like below:

```
const RequireAuth = (Component) => { 
    class App extends Component { 
        componentWillMount() { 
            const getToken = localStorage.getItem('token'); 
            if(!getToken) { 
               this.props.history.replace({pathname: '/'}); 
            } 
        } 
        render() { 
           return <Component {...this.props} /> 
        }
    } 
    return new App();
} 

export { RequireAuth };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply transform it to a functional component, which can be called instead of a class. And instead of `componentWillMount` use `useEffect` with an empty dependency array.

```
const RequireAuth = Component => props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const getToken = localStorage.getItem("token");
    if (!getToken) {
      props.history.replace({ pathname: "/" });
    }
  }, []);
  return <Component {...props} />;
};
```